# Virtual host issues

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have an ubuntu server hosted on Linode with a lot of sites in the **/var/www** directory.

I've got 2 registered domains(**preplogs.com, icerge.com and alot of other sites I access via 8.8.8.8/domain**) each of them point at sub directories in the */var/www* directory.

My problem is my virtual hosts definitions are not responding as I intend.

I've got the default **000-default.conf** host with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www

        LimitRequestFieldSize 100000

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

The second vhost is called *icerge.conf*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/icerge

        LimitRequestFieldSize 100000

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

And the third domain is called *preplogs.com*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName www.preplogs.com
        ServerAlias preplogs.com
        ServerAlias www.preplog.com
        ServerAlias preplog.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/DrupalQuiz

        LimitRequestFieldSize 100000

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that I don't get the right site when I visit different addresses.

When I visit the IP address I expect to see the 'index of' listings of all the domains on the server but instead I see the *preplogs* site.

Preplogs.com loads the preplogs site as expected.

icerge.com loads the 'index of' listings of the server.

Can anyone help? I'm not sure how to untangle this mess.

Comment: Why haven't you set ServerName in some of the VirtualHosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set up the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` on the two first vhost configs.

1. Set up a default vhost, which will handle cases of IP address used, or similar. Leave ServerName blank for this one.
2. Set up a vhost for each of your sites. These *should* contain the `ServerName` and possible `ServerAlias`.

You probably want to set the `ServerAdmin` field as well, as this is used on error pages, as a point of contact.

Comment: Dude, thank  you so much. I feel so silly but I thank you :-)